# iOS RestKit loggging doesn't print anything

Tags: ios, restkit

I would like to user RestKit's network logging with the following code:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

I am creating GET/POST requests and nothing is printed to the console. I am using Xcode 6.1.1.
Anybody has any clues why it isn't printing anything to the console?

---

Edit:
`RestKit initialization:`

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:[RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:self.baseURL]];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:[IPCoreDataHelper sharedInstance].persistentStoreCoordinator];
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

[RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];

[self setMappings];
```

After this, for example, the user will press the login button and the following code is executed
`Login:`

```
// ... Setup the user object
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] requestWithObject:user method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"login/" parameters:nil];
urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 300;
RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:urlRequest managedObjectContext:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    // Do something with login success
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Failed
}];
[operation start];
```

Comment: Where in your code do you call to set the log level? Where is your RestKit GET call (show the code)?

Comment: You have the code. Do you have any clues?

Comment: Not really. Make sure it's called. Can't think of many reasons off the top of my head and haven't looked through the logging code...